# set one view textfied value to another view label

Tags: objective-c

I am having textfield and Button In firstview .When I click the Button, it Navigate the secondview .In that I am having one label.
My Question is I want to set the textfield value to label text ?

Plz help me!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can Create one global Variable for your first view controller to store the text feild value and just create a reference of first viewcontroller class in your second view controller...Then you can access the variable

Answer (score 5):

By creating an ivar to refer back to a specific type such as a label or other view controller, you are coupling things together that aren't necessary to couple. What you could do instead is make your first tab view controller a delegate of your second tab view controller. So do something like this in your app delegate.

```
OptionsViewController *optionsViewController = // ... get this from the tab view
FirsTabViewController *firstTabViewController = // ... same here

[optionsViewController setDelegate:firsTabViewController];
```

Which means that you need an ivar in your OptionsViewController:

```
@property (assign) id delegate;
```

Then, when whatever event you want to trigger the change occurs in your options view controller, see if the delegate can respond to a selector you've named. For example:

```
- (void)someEventHappenedLikeTyping:(id)sender;
{
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(setOptionsString:)]
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(setOptionsString:) withObject:[label text]];
}
```

Notice you never specified any specific object types. You just check to see if the delegate (which was declared as id) can respond to that selector. If it can, it does what it's told and just is silent otherwise.

For this to work, you need an ivar for the optionsString in your FirstTabViewController and so it would be declared in the header as:

```
@property (copy) NSString *optionsString;
```

and then @synthesize it in the .m. This causes -setOptionsString to become a valid selector that will get called in the -someEventHappenedLikeTyping method.

Anyhow, now, if you ever need to to change which view controller references which, you don't have to go into the header and change the type of ivar referenced. You simply need to implement the selector (this is known as an informal protocol, by the way) in the view controller that is a delegate of your options view controller.

Just some food for thought there. Hope that helps. There is further de-coupling that could be done in the code I've added, but again it may be overkill for such a simple task. Let me know if you need clarification or want to understand what I mean by further decoupling.

Best regards,

p.s. Sometimes needing to share data between two tab bar view controllers, means you have a design flaw. If you are wanting to store preferences from your options view, you should just call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[label text] forKey:@"option1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then you can pull from the NSUserDefaults back in your main tab with;

```
NSString *option1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"option1"];
```

// Do something with option1

**Reference By** [How to access data from one view to another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008967/how-to-access-data-from-one-view-to-another-view)